# Is it possible to update FormsAuthentication cookie value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, setcookie, formsauthentication

I have to set `FormsAuthentication` cookie value (`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserDesignation, false)`) at the time of login.
Now I need to provide designation change option. So when user change their designation, I need to update the `FormsAuthentication` cookie value from old designation to new designation.

Is it possible to do that?

If yes means, how can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the cookie data as shown below, but it is preferable as per me to keep the role in a separate cookie and authenticate it using the FormsAuthentication cookie

```
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Username, true);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                              ticket.Name,
                                              ticket.IssueDate,
                                              ticket.Expiration,
                                              true, //persistent 
                                              "user data,designation",
                                              ticket.CookiePath);

cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
cookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration.AddHours(2);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: So, we can't able to change Name property value in FormsAuthendication cookie. we can able to change user data only. right?

Comment: yes, if you change the cookie name, it will be treated as a new cookie. If you want to go with that approach, then after authentication just delete the old cookie and create a new cookie.

Comment: I would want to change the value of `User.Identity.Name`. In above code, it is equivalent `ticket.Name`. Thank you ;)